# How to configure capistrano to deploy puma and nginx on one server and resque on another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma, capistrano3

I am preparing capistrano to deploy ruby on rails application to AWS. The application servers will be behind bastian host.

I have two servers server1 and server2. I want to deploy and run puma, nginx on server1, and run resque workers and resque schedulers on server2. I know about roles and here is my configuration so far:

```
# deploy/production.rb
web_instances = [web-instance-ip]
worker_instances = [worker-instance-ip]
role :app, web_instances
role :web, web_instances
role :worker, worker_instances

set :deploy_user, ENV['DEPLOY_USER'] || 'ubuntu'
set :branch, 'master'
set :ssh_options, {
  forward_agent: true,
  keys: ENV['SSH_KEY_PATH'],
  proxy: Net::SSH::Proxy::Command.new("ssh -i '#{ENV['SSH_KEY_PATH']}' #{fetch(:deploy_user)}@#{ENV['BASTIAN_PUBLIC_IP']} -W %h:%p"),
}

set :puma_role, :app
```

I am not sure what should I do or how to write tasks by making sure that puma start, restart is done on only server1 and resque, resque scheduler start restart etc is handled on only server2. While common tasks such as pulling latest code, bundle install etc is done on each instance?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume, you have defined the roles in the following manner

```
role :puma_nginx_role, 'server1.com'
role :resque_role, 'server2.com'
```

Now define a rake task in your **config/deploy.rb** file, ex:

```
namespace :git do
  desc 'To push the code'
  task :push do
    execute "git push"
  end
end
```

Now assuming the above example should be run on server1, all you have do is

```
namespace :git do
  desc 'To push the code'
  task :push, :roles => [:puma_nginx_role] do
    execute "git push"
  end
end
```

Thereby, your telling capistrano configuration, that the **git:push** should be executed on role **:puma_nginx_role**, which in-turn would run it on **server1.com**. You'll have to modify the *tasks* to run **puma**/**nginx**/**resque** and make changes based on roles.

Answer (score 1):

This can achieve by using `role` to limit the tasks to be run for each servers and some hooks to trigger your custom tasks. Your `deploy/production.rb` file will look something similar to this.

```
web_instances = [web-instance-ip]
worker_instances = [worker-instance-ip]
role :app, web_instances
role :web, web_instances
role :worker, worker_instances

set :deploy_user, ENV['DEPLOY_USER'] || 'ubuntu'
set :branch, 'master'
set :ssh_options, {
  forward_agent: true,
  keys: ENV['SSH_KEY_PATH'],
  proxy: Net::SSH::Proxy::Command.new("ssh -i '#{ENV['SSH_KEY_PATH']}' #{fetch(:deploy_user)}@#{ENV['BASTIAN_PUBLIC_IP']} -W %h:%p"),
}

# This will run on server with web role only
namespace :puma do
  task :restart do
    on roles(:web) do |host|
      with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
        ** Your code to restart puma server **
      end
    end
  end
end

# This will run on server with worker role only
namespace :resque do
  task :restart do
    on roles(:worker) do |host|
      with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
        ** Your code to restart resque server **
      end
    end
  end
end

after :deploy, 'puma:restart'
after :deploy, 'resque:restart'
```

Check out the [docs](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/tasks/) for more information about commands and hooks to setup your deployment.